# Visual studio for mac not building

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin

When I build my project in debug mode it builds forever. However there is no problem building in release mode.

This problem first occurred when I updated visual studio for mac to the newest version:

> Preview 6 (7.0 build 2740).

This is what my debug settings look like:

[image]

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check for xamarin.forms updates in both in the ios and xamarin project. It could be that theese are not updated even though the solution is updated.

[image: Xamarin.forms package under the iOS project might have an older version]

Xamarin.forms package under the iOS project might have an older version

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really help you because I don't know what type of project you tried to run or which OS X you are working with.

If such an Error occurs, always check your code or try restarting your mac.

*Tip:* "Visual Studio for Mac Preview" is still in its Alpha. Use the Stable Update channel to avoid errors like this.

Comment: I'm working with latest version of OS X. Code is working fine, and mac has been restarted several times. As I am aware of there are no stable update channels available for the visual studio for mac, only Alpha are available. Do you know if there are any ways to "roll back" the update?

Comment: save your projects and reinstall visualstudio